# how to pass observable from angular bottomsheet to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to pass data from angular material bottomsheet to its parent component.

Like we have `[mat-dialog-close]` directive in angular material dialog component where we can pass data from dialog to parent like as mentioned in
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogClose

dialog html:

```
<button [mat-dialog-close]="'dataWhichNeedsToBePassed'" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

and recieve in parent component as:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result); //dataWhichNeedsToBePassed
});
```

similarly, I need to pass data from bottomsheet to parent component(from where bottomsheet has been called).

Looks like there is no predefined directive present in https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/api

what could be the best solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from `.dismiss()` function.
Just need to pass data from this dismiss function

bottomsheet.html:

`<button (click)="confirmDelete()">Delete<button>`

bottomsheetComponent:

```
confirmDelete(): void {
  this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss('Deleted');
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

parent Component:

```
MatBottomSheetRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('bottomsheet was closed');
  console.log(result); //Deleted
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in the same way as mat dialog

```
this._bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet)
.afterDismissed().subscribe((result) => {
   console.log(result);
   console.log('Bottom sheet has been dismissed.');
 });
```

example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nftwrd?file=src/app/bottom-sheet-overview-example.ts)